# SSH File Transfer from Mint to RPi works not bidirectional

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi4

I am new to Linux and RPi. I want to transfer a file from my Pi to my PC.

With ...

```
scp hello pi@192.168.1.101:/home/pi
```

.. I am able to transfer my file "hell" to my Pi.

But when I try to send the file "elle" with ...

```
scp elle mirco@192.168.1.104:/home/mirco
```

i get

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.104 port 22: Connection timed out lost connection
```

I read the ssh service status from the pi and my Computer:

Pi:

```
    ● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-04-08 14:38:18 CEST; 6s ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
  Process: 14004 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 14006 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 804.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─14006 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Apr 08 14:38:18 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Apr 08 14:38:18 raspberrypi sshd[14006]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Apr 08 14:38:18 raspberrypi sshd[14006]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Apr 08 14:38:18 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

My Computer:

```
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-04-08 14:52:26 CEST; 6min ago
  Process: 9224 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9216 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8934 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8935 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4578)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─8935 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Apr 08 14:52:26 ComputerMirco systemd[1]: Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Apr 08 14:52:26 ComputerMirco systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 08 14:52:26 ComputerMirco sshd[8935]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Apr 08 14:52:26 ComputerMirco systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Apr 08 14:52:26 ComputerMirco systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 08 14:58:12 ComputerMirco systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 08 14:58:12 ComputerMirco sshd[8935]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
Apr 08 14:58:12 ComputerMirco sshd[8935]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Mirco

Comment: Besides the potential auth issue (keypairs are one direction only) I'm wondering if you are also hitting up against your windows firewall. You may need to add an exception for port 22 in windows.

Comment: I think you should tweak the firewall. Also make sure that you are sending the files to the user's home directories! Otherwise `scp` fails.

Answer (score 1):

Am I correct in thinking you're running the second SCP command on your Pi? If so, your Pi isn't authorized to connect to your PC. You can add it's public key to your authorized_keys file and your Pi will be able to connect to your PC.

You could also pull the file in from your Pi. This is safer because you don't really want your Pi to be able to connect to your PC.

SCP copy to host example

```
scp pi@192.168.1.101:/home/pi/elle /home/mirco
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your PC doesn't have ssh enabled.

Install openssh-server on your PC using
 `sudo apt install openssh-server`

After installing this, a system service called ssh should have become active.

You can test this using

```
sudo systemctl status ssh
```

Your output should look something like this

```
 ● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-04-08 10:05:07 IST; 13h ago
```

If it doesn't show active(running), try executing

```
sudo systemctl enable ssh
```

If you still are not able to ssh, enable the ssh port through your firewall.

In Ubuntu this can be done by

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```